# Why is my LocalDateTime variable changing by 5 hours when I get from my sql to my spring-boot application?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, datetime, jackson, timezone

**My LocalDateTime variable changes by 5 hours every time I get it by querying my sql table. If I have a time that starts at 9:30am then it'll return 4:30am as the time.**
Whenever I try to get a datetime type field from my sql table by querying it in my repo

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT start FROM course_section WHERE crn = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    LocalDateTime getStartTimeByCrn(int term);
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT end FROM course_section WHERE crn = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    LocalDateTime getEndTimeByCrn(int term);
```

I send it to my service

```
//Method to get the Start time for Section class
public LocalDateTime getStartTimeByCrn(int term) {
    LocalDateTime start = (LocalDateTime) repo.getStartTimeByCrn(term);
    return start;
}
//Method to get the End time for the Section class
public LocalDateTime getEndTimeByCrn(int term) {
    LocalDateTime end = (LocalDateTime) repo.getEndTimeByCrn(term);
    return end;
```

and my controller uses the methods

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accepted", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addSchedule(@ModelAttribute("schedule") Schedule schedule) throws JsonProcessingException {
    
        int crn = schedule.getCrn();
        
        Section sec = new Section();
        
        //set all the attributes of Section object 
        
        sec.setStart(service.getStartTimeByCrn(crn));
        sec.setEnd(service.getEndTimeByCrn(crn));
        
//      String stringToJson = new JsonMapper().writeValueAsString(sec);
        
        service.save(sec);
        
        System.out.print( sec.getStart() + " is the subject!!!"); 
        return "calendar";
    }
```

My datetime variable in a row will change by five hours when I get it by the crn from my sql table. Nothing else is changed, not the year, month, day, min, or sec.

My @Entity LocalDateTime variables look like

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime start; 

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime end;
```

There seems like there is no logical reason for this bug to happen...

Comment: depends on where mysql db is hosted. Can you check if mysql is hosted in cloud service provider in a region whose timezone is 4 hours ahead of yours

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and timestamp behaviour can be vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What data type are the columns `start` and `end` in the database?